# Query and return object from a nested array in MongoDB document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am searching documents and matching by a property within a nested array.

The find function seems to work fine, but I can't seem to find a way to manipulate the object once found.

The document is like so:

```js
{
  _id: "6124da1a014c141e119f123a",
  viewed_resources: [
    {
      resource: "6124da1a014c141e119f634a",
      isVideo: true
    }
  ]
}
```

Code is below:

```js
User.findOne({
  _id: context.user._id,
  'viewed_resources.resource': "6124da1a014c141e119f634a",
})
.lean()
.select({ viewed_resources: 1 })
.exec((err, res) => {
   if (!res) {
     console.log('ERR', err);
   } else {
     const index = res.viewed_resources.findIndex(
       (e) => e.resource === "6124da1a014c141e119f634a"
     );
     // Index always returns -1 despite object being present in the array
     console.log('INDEX', index);


    const object = res.viewed_resources.find(
       (e) => e.resource === "6124da1a014c141e119f634a"
     );
     // Returns undefined
     console.log('OBJ', object);
   }
});
```

The issue is, no matter what I query inside the matched response, always returns undefined (or in the above example, -1 for the index despite it being present in the array.

I feel I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Are you sure `findOne` is returning the object? If `context.user._id` is a String maybe you have to parse to `ObjectId`.

Comment: FYI, you can use `$` operator to select first matching element base on condition. More info here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

Comment: @J.F. yes console logging the response does return the correct object without ObjectId.  I've added in ObjectId(X) to be sure and still the same result.